# How to print state of model in Federated learning

Tags: tensorflow-federated, federated-learning

I would like to print (before training) the state of model :
with  `print(state['model'])`,
I found this error :

```
TypeError: 'ServerState' object is not subscriptable
```

Answer (score 2):

[`tff.leraning.framework.ServerState`](https://www.tensorflow.org/federated/api_docs/python/tff/learning/framework/ServerState) is a Python [attrs class](https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/), whos fields are accessed via the `Instance.method` (`__getattr_`) syntax, rather than the `Instance['key']` lookup (`__getitem__`).

Try replacing `print(state['model'])` with `print(state.model)`.